# Error con el formato de un ciclo foreach, servicio web

Tags: php, ciclos

Estoy creando un cliente en php, que consume un servicio web en php, al intentar ejecutar el cliente en el navegador aparece un mensaje,

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\xampp\htdocs\04_soap_mysql\index.php on line 14

¿saben como corregir el mensaje de alerta?

Más abajo les muestro el código del cliente

```
<?php
    require_once "lib/nusoap.php"; // referencia de una libreria para utilizar una de sus funciones internas

    // la linea inferior hace una instacia del servicio web y creamos un objeto llamado cliente que usa el servicio web
    $cliente = new nusoap_client ("http://localhost/04_soap_mysql/soap_server.php");

    $libros = $cliente->call("MuestraLibros"); // llamado del servicio
    $planetas = $cliente->call("MuestraPlanetas");
    // impresión de los renglons
    echo "<h2>Mis libros</h2>";
    echo "<ul>";
    echo $planetas;

        foreach($libros as $renglon)
        {
            echo '<li>';
            echo '<strong>'.$renglon['autor'].'</strong><br>';
            echo $renglon['titulo'];
            echo '<br><br></li>';
        }  
        echo "</ul>";
    ?>
```

La función del servicio web

```
// la conexión del servidor y la aplicación
    $mi_usuario = "root";
    $mi_contrasenia = "";
    $direccion = "localhost";
    $mi_bd = "phpws";

$conexion = mysqli_connect($direccion, $mi_usuario, $mi_contrasenia, $mi_bd)            
or die("no se puede conectar a la base de datos".mysql_error());


// inica Muestra libros
function MuestraLibros()
{
$consulta = "SELECT * FROM libros";
$resultadoConsulta = mysqli_query($conexion, $consulta);

    while($tabla = mysqli_fetch_array($resultadoConsulta))
    {
        $contenido = $contenido."<tr>
                                    <td>".$contenido['autor']."</td>
                                    <td>".$contenido['titulo']."</td>                                    
                                </tr>";
    }    
    return $contenido;
}
// termina MuestroLibros
```

Comment: Disculpa Stephen como resolviste el detalle de la variable libros ya que estoy atorado en algo similar. Saludos

Comment: antes del `foreach` chequea `if (is_array($libros))` ó `if (!empty($libros))` lo mas seguro es que retorne vacía

Comment: Hola gustavo, no me acuerdo exactamente que hice para resolverlo, pero tres dias despues encontré que se puede depurar codigo php, e ir viendo paso a paso que hace el código, para eso, instalé un editor de codigo llamado Visual Studio code y una extension llamada Xdebug, me parece que ahora ya viene integrada en el editor, antes no, busca un video de como usarlo, espero de verdad te ayude

Answer (score 1):

La variable $libros no es un array, puedes hacer un var_dump($libros) para verificar por pantalla el contenido.

Comment: Gracias de verdad gracias, me acaba de aparecer un mensaje donde me dice que el valor de retorno es un bool(false)